# Transforming Informatica to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, transformation, informatica

I am attempting to recreate some queries a colleague developed in informatica. However, I am trying to transform the query into `SQL Server`. I was able to easily convert the `SUBSTR` to `substring`, however, I am a little stuck.

The original code reads:

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(substring(COV_BK,11, INSTR(COV_BK, '|',1,3)-INSTR(COV_BK, '|',1,2)-1 )))+'C'
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: use `charindex` for `instr`. The complex part is that you will have to find the 2nd and 3rd occurrences of `|` character after the 11th character in the string.

Comment: Do you know what that piece of code is supposed to do?  Or you're just trying to replicate it's behavior without actually knowing how it behaves?  If you know the expected behavior, then it will be much easier to help.